# ASIHTTPRequest with iPhone 3G

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest in my project and i have a problem with iPhone 3G.
i send a request to :

```
NSURL* pageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=sj"];
loginPageRequest = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:pageURL];
[loginPageRequest setTimeOutSeconds:30];
[loginPageRequest setDelegate:self];
[loginPageRequest startAsynchronous];
```

and in other devices i get a responde to :

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
```

and in iPhone 3G i get a lot of times :

```
- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
```

with error MSG : `The request timed out`

i set the the request timeout to 30 seconds.

any idea why it happen?

Comment: may be your ASIHTTPRequest in 3G require more time, so change 30 to 90 and try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this problem on iPhone 3G!
I figured out it was a HTTP**S** (SSL) problem. My "valid" certificate was flagged as invalid.

You might add `[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];` to your request.

If you are lucky you have the same problem. :)