# ASIHTTPRequest wierd on 3G

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I want to download a file using ASIHTTPRequest, with the following method:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request;
request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:downloadServer]];
[request setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"download" forKey:@"download"]];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(downloadIsFinished:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(downloadIsFailed:)];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:40];
[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:self];
[request setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

If I'm on Wifi everything's fine, but if I'm on 3G then my method tries to download the file but after 10 seconds the downloadIsFinish delegate fires, but my file hasn't actually been downloaded....

Comment: How strong is your 3G network, and do you have HSPA (3G+)?  Maybe the network is not good enough.

Comment: Nah, with a Speedtest App, i get a download with 2000MBit/s...So it must be strong enough!

Comment: I seem to remember seeing this problem before on SO.  Could it be this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086768/asihttprequest-with-iphone-3g?rq=1

Comment: Nope, my URL has not https...:(

Comment: Last updated: 15th May 2011
Perhaps there is a problem with iOS 6 oder new devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of thing is usually a bug caused by not implementing the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods correctly. One visible side-effect can be half-downloaded images appearing in your UI.

For example, if the server disconnects before you have received the entire response, no error is raised by `NSURLConnection`. `connectionDidFinishLoading:` is called as usual. You have to explicitly check that the number of bytes you received is equal to the number specified in the `Content-Length` header (if it was present). If you haven't received all the data, you need to raise an error yourself.

Note that development of `ASIHTTPRequest` has stopped. See [this blog post from its creator](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D;).

Most people seem to recommend [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) nowadays, although last time I checked they also didn't handle this case of early disconnects.

Comment: hmm, i would like to Use AFNetworking, but it requires ARC and my Project was build without it...:( What do you mean by not implementing the NSURLConnectionDelegate methods correctly?!

Comment: You can use AFNetworking even if the rest of your project does not use ARC.

Comment: And what I mean by "not implementing the NSURLConnectionDelegate methods correctly" is that lots of code, even that of the popular libraries like ASI/AFNetworking still doesn't handle certain edge cases like the example I gave.